# Why was the following question closed?

Tags: discussion, closing, exact-duplicates

I just saw that the following question was closed for being a duplicate:

[In The Old Republic ship-based minigame, is there a way to destroy shielded targets?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43555/in-the-old-republic-ship-based-minigame-is-there-a-way-to-destroy-shielded-targ)

However, this question was asked an hour before the other one even existed.. so, how can one avoid doing such "duplicate" questions?

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I originally closed the later question as a duplicate, because it was, as observed, a duplicate.

This meant we had a closed question *with* an answer linking to an open question *without* an answer.

That's probably the opposite of what we want, so I reversed the chain, closing the earlier one, and linking it to the later one.

Time of posting is the *primary* determinator for closing as duplicate, but it is not the *only* one.

Comment: Hmm, I'd put time as the last criteria.  Views, links, quality, answers, etc. are all more important.

Comment: @MatthewRead if we spot the duplicate soon enough, the latter should all be null. We didn't in this case.